# ProgressBar Background Property not working in Windows Store Apps

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, progress-bar, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I added a `ProgressBar` to my application and I wanted it to have a transparent background, so I  did it like this:

```
<ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ProgressBar.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.5" />
    </ProgressBar.Background>
</ProgressBar>
```

And in the Preview Window everything looks fine, however, when I run my app, the `Background` is simply not there. The solution I found to this is to put the `ProgressBar` in a Grid and set the `Background` property in the `Grid`, but since the Preview shows it right, and the property is there, shouldn't it work?

**UPDATE:**
Based on @Chris W. suggestion, I tried to override the default style of the `ProgressBar` element, like so:

```
<ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" Background="#FF000000" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="50">
    <ProgressBar.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DeterminateRoot"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 To="0.5"
                                                 Duration="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ProgressBar.Style>
</ProgressBar>
```

But still, no juice.

Comment: It's possible that the ProgressBar has some kind of styling (likely a VisualState) which would change the background without showing up properly in the designer. You can try editing the Style or getting the default one off of MSDN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to get rid of two (2) StoryBoard Animations

> Document Outline > Right Click Progress Bar > Edit Template -> Edit A Copy

```
<!--
<FadeOutThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DeterminateRoot"/>
<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="DeterminateRoot"/>
-->
```

---

And as [@ricochete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367668/progressbar-background-property-not-working-in-windows-store-apps#comment41414115_26370937) suggested if using Opacity = 1 change up the Z-Order of DeterminateRoot to be on top of the EllipseGrid

```XAML
<Border x:Name="DeterminateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}">
    <Rectangle x:Name="ProgressBarIndicator" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
</Border>
<Grid x:Name="EllipseGrid" Opacity="0">
<!-- ... more XAML Style -->
```

---

```XAML
<Grid Background="#FFFF0000">
    <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" Style="{StaticResource ProgressBarStyle1}" Height="50" >
        <ProgressBar.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.5"/>
        </ProgressBar.Background>
    </ProgressBar>
</Grid>
```

---

[image]

Comment: +1 simply for looking closer than I did and seeing the other one, that's what I get for breezing through these questions with lack of attention.

Comment: Although this works, the Background is on top of the Loading animation, i.e., if I set the opacity to 1 I can't see the loading animation. The Border element `DeterminateRoot` has to be placed before the `EllipseGrid` element, so the overlapping does not occur. Please add this to your answer so I can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

If you go look at the [default template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709923.aspx) you'll see at the bottom of the template the `Background` only has a `TemplateBinding` in one spot for `x:Name="DeterminateRoot"` so that's the only place you'd see your color set from the Background property.

Then if you climb up through the Storyboard for the Indeterminate State you'll find;

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DeterminateRoot"
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                 To="0"
                 Duration="0" />
```

...and you've got your ProgressBar set to `IsIndeterminate="True"` so you're setting the one place that accepts the Background property to a zero opacity explicitly.

So you could go pull that animation out of the Storyboard for that state, or put in your own new object to set your thing, or just do the workaround you mentioned by just throwing it in a `Border` or a `Grid` or something and doing it that way amongst other possibilities.

You might also try (once you've fixed your opacity setting issue from the storyboard) just flipping your `SolidColorBrush` with `Opacity` into just pure hex with the Alpha Channel set as 50% opacity equivalent. Making it just;

```
<ProgressBar Background="#80000000" IsIndeterminate="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Anyhow, hope this helps, Cheers!

Comment: The second solution you mentioned does not work, as it would have been great. Can you please post an example of the first suggestion, so if it works I can mark it as answer?

Comment: So you went and pulled that animation out of your ProgressBar Style template, and it did not work?

Comment: I hope you're not referring to the "You might also try" part, that's contingent on fixing how that object is set to 0 opacity first, which would make me wonder if you read the whole answer?

Comment: My bad, I should have had a closer look. I tried overriding the default style, however, it did not work. Could you add a piece of code that you tested and worked to your answer?

Comment: How about you show what you tried and I'll show you how to fix it. :)

Comment: I added the code I used to test your suggestion, but I'm doing something wrong because it does not work.